# prevent line break spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm having this site with a *n* number of tiles (the yellow elements in the picture). When the sites gets too small to put them on one line it obviously put them in a second row. But somehow it has this space between them. There are no spaces in between the elements in the source.
Does anyone know how I can remove this space? I know I could use a table, but is there really no easier method?

The tiles (yellow) in their container (blue)

[image]

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(66, 134, 244, .2);
  padding: 5px;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(232, 223, 55, .2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div></div>
```

Comment: Can't repro! http://jsbin.com/kirigohawu/edit?html,css,output and I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19yft.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inline-block` elements are causing you trouble. You can set `font-size: 0px` on the container, to get rid of the small margin:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(66, 134, 244, .2);
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d67ms48j/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use in the CSS the margin-top method.

For example:

> margin-top:-5px;

try to set different values untill the space between the elements will be removed.

Comment: That's not a really nice solution...